# Gerar caracteres aleatórios em SQL

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Olá, tenho uma dúvida no PHP My Admin que é a seguinte:
-tenho uma tabela que preciso de colocar como valor padrão numa coluna um valor aleatório.
Alguém me podia dar uma luz sobre este assunto?
Eu sei como fazer um `TRIGGER` no PHP My Admin, o problema é criar uma cadeia de caracteres aleatório.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737910/generating-a-random-unique-8-character-string-using-mysql   veja se ajuda

Comment: Olá, essa maneira que explicam não funciona no `PHP My Admin`. Podia me fornecer outra maneira?